# Gaussian Mixture Model - Matlab training for parameters

Tags: algorithm, matlab, signal-processing

I am running a speech enhancement algorithm based on Gaussian Mixture Model. The problem is that the estimation algorithm underflows during the training processing.
I am trying to calculate the PDF of a log spectrum frame `X` given a Gaussian cluster which is a product of the PDF of each frequnecy component `X_k` (fft is done for k=1..256)
what i get is a product of `256 exp(-v(k))` such that `v(k)>=0`

Here is a snippet of the MATLAB calculation:
`N` - number of frames; `M`- number of mixtures; `c_i` weight for each mixture;

`gamma(n,i) = c_i*f(X_n|I = i)`

```
 for i=1 : N
    rep_DataMat(:,:,i) = repmat(DataMat(:,i),1,M); 
    gamma_exp(:,:) = (1./sqrt((2*pi*sigmaSqr_curr))).*exp(((-1)*((rep_DataMat(:,:,i) - mue_curr).^2)./(2*sigmaSqr_curr)));
    gamma_curr(i,:) = c_curr.*(prod(10*gamma_exp(:,:),1));
    alpha_curr(i,:) = gamma_curr(i,:)./sum(gamma_curr(i,:));
end
```

The product goes quickly to zero due to K = 256 since the numbers being smaller then one. Is there a way I can calculate this with causing an underflow (like logsum or similar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the computations in the log domain.

The conversion of products into sums is straightforward. 
Sums on the other hand can be converted with something such as [logsumexp](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26184-em-algorithm-for-gaussian-mixture-model/content/emgm/logsumexp.m). 
This works using the formula:

```
log(a + b) = log(exp(log(a)) + exp(log(b)))
           = log(exp(loga) + exp(logb))
```

Where `loga` and `logb` are the respective representation of `a` and `b` in the log domain.
The basic idea is then to factorize the exponent with the largest argument (eg. `loga` for sake of illustration):

```
 log(exp(loga)+exp(logb)) = log(exp(loga)*(1+exp(logb-loga)))
                          = loga + log(1+exp(logb-loga))
```

Note that the same idea applies if you have more than 2 terms to add.